# How to convert socket message to json format in Python?

Tags: python, json, sockets

I have the following line which receives a string upon incoming web request.

```
data_from_flask = c.recv(2048).decode('utf8')
```

The message is

```
'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:31477\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nsec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="105", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="105"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: cross-site\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\nSec-Fetch-User: ?1\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n\r\n'
```

I want to load this to a JSON format using

```
job_json = json.loads(data_from_flask)
```

If I directly run this, I get the following error

> The exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

because the incoming string is not entirely in JSON format.

What is the simplest way I could do this? Is there any special encoding I could use ?

Comment: json.loads() can't possibly work if the value passed isn't in JSON format. What you have is HTTP headers. **You** need to decide what your Python dictionary needs to look like then you can convert to JSON if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a string that represents HTTP headers. You can parse this to make a Python dictionary which can subsequently be converted to JSON.

For example:

```
import json

headers = """GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:31477\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nsec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="105", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="105"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: cross-site\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\nSec-Fetch-User: ?1\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n\r\n"""

tokens = headers.split('\r\n')
pd = {}

for t in tokens[1:]: # skip the protocol
    k, *v = t.split(':')
    if k:
        pd[k] = ':'.join(v).strip()

print(json.dumps(pd, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Host": "localhost:31477",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"105\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"105\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}
```